# Wix custom dialog error 2856

Tags: wix

I've a wix installation with a custom dialog added into the installation: *ProgramDataInstallDlg*

This is what my UI-tag look like for the whole project:

```
<UI Id="my_UI">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
  <DialogRef  Id="ProgramDataInstallDlg" />

  <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgramDataInstallDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgramDataInstallDlg">1</Publish>
</UI>
```

Everything works fine if only next is pressed. But if back button is pressed in VerifyReadyDlg or next button in CustomizeDlg is pressed. I get error 2856.

This is what the installation log says:

```
DEBUG: Error 2856:  Creating a second copy of the dialog ProgramDataInstallDlg
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2856. The arguments are: ProgramDataInstallDlg, , 
MSI (c) (E0:6C) [14:06:34:526]: Product: MOPS 4.0 -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2856. The arguments are: ProgramDataInstallDlg, ,
```

Whats wrong?

EDIT ProgramDataInstallDlg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI>    
        <Dialog Id="ProgramDataInstallDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="yes">

          <!--Banner UI-components-->
          <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Custom Setup" />
          <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="text" />
          <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
          <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />

          <!--Content Components-->

          <Control Id="NameLabel" Type="Text" X="45" Y="73" Width="220" Height="15" TabSkip="no" Text="text" />       


          <!--Bottom UI-components-->
          <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
          <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="173" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Back">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
          </Control>          
          <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="230" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
          </Control>
          <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
          </Control>

        </Dialog>
      </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are customizing the UI I suggest to create a custom WixUI_FeatureTree.

Take a look at the code below. I took the default template and used your dialog name in the appropriate places.

From your custom dialog remove the following lines:

```
<Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
```

The main dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI Id="WixUI_FeatureTreeCustom">
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

            <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
            <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="FeatureTree" />

            <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
            <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
            <DialogRef Id="ProgramDataInstallDlg" />

            <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="1">Installed</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" Order="2">NOT Installed</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgramDataInstallDlg">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="ProgramDataInstallDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="ProgramDataInstallDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgramDataInstallDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="3">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="ChangeButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
        </UI>

        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Why would WixUI_FeatureTree be better?

Comment: Please add the custom dialog ProgramDataInstallDlg.

Comment: ProgramDataInstallDlg added

Comment: I understand your idea but now. but now the .wxs file for the custom dialog complains about the buttons does nothing. ICE17: PushButton: 'Next' of Dialog: 'ProgramDataInstallDlg' does not have an event defined in the ControlEvent table. It is a 'Do Nothing' button.

Comment: After testing some more, it finally worked. Don't know why I got earlier error message. Thanks!

Comment: The key difference why you got the earlier error message is because you used a SpawnDialog Event instead of a NewDialog Event. The SpawnDialog works in way where the parent dialog still exists (things like browsing for files). If you use the spawndialog for navigation and go back, the system will create a second copy of the dialog, a dialog that was still running. This is why you got the error. It might help others.